# Jaeger Collector and Jaeger Query Authentication

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, open-telemetry, jaeger

Noob question here since I'm new to Jaeger and Docker.

Docker Image: **Jaeger Version 1.40**

Is there a way to secure the Jaeger Collector OTLP endpoint by adding a basic authentication when building the image? I wanted to have a secured connection when sending trace data from the Collector to the Jaeger Collector via OTLP. (Port 4317 and 4318)

Also is there a way for the Jaeger Query to be secured when someone tries to access it by adding a basic authentication? Adding a TLS to the UI and accessing it thru the browser returns an empty black page. (Port 16686)

I deployed the built image in AWS ECS and launched it as AWS EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to have a secured connection when sending trace data from the Collector to the Jaeger Collector via OTLP

No, AFAIK Jaeger doesn't support configuring TLS for its Collector servers. However, you could add reverse proxy in front of the collectors. See this blog for more details https://medium.com/@larsmilland01/secure-architecture-for-jaeger-with-apache-httpd-reverse-proxy-on-openshift-f31983fad400

> Adding a TLS to the UI and accessing it thru the browser returns an empty black page. (Port 16686)

Also No, You could do with sidecar proxy, Read this https://medium.com/jaegertracing/protecting-jaeger-ui-with-an-oauth-sidecar-proxy-34205cca4bb1

Comment: The first part of the answer is incorrect - collector does support TLS, see `--collector.grpc.tls.enabled` and similar flags. This is described in the official docs https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.44/security/